# JavaMail: Sending Mail via 1und1 gives 550 Error

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

A friend of mine has a new website and i build him a tool to organize email-addresses and send newsletters (HTML-Messages). Therefore i use the javax.mail library. While developing i sent all mails from my gmail account and it worked fine. But now, for "production", i want to send the mails from his domain, which is hosted by 1und1.

I am able to connect successfully to the 1und1 smtp-Server, but as soon as i send a mail, i get the following errors:

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 550-Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable
550 invalid DNS MX or A/AAAA resource record
```

When sending from the online 1und1 webmailer, i can send to any mailadress without errors.

These are the props i set for mailing. Like i said, i can connect to the server with these information, but sending fails.

```
Properties props = new Properties();

// Zum Senden
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable" , "true");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", configurationService.getMailHost()); // smtp.1und1.de
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", configurationService.getMailAuth().toString()); // true
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", configurationService.getMailPort()); // 587
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", user);
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.password", pass);

return Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(props.getProperty("mail.smtp.user"),
                props.getProperty("mail.smtp.password"));
    }
});
```

Thanks for help!

Edit: When Debugging the Session, i get the following line just before the exception occurs:

```
MAIL FROM: <USER@LAPTOP-Name.fritz.box>
```

How can i change this to something accepted?

Comment: You need to use a From address that's associated with the domain of the mail server you're using, or you need to do something on the mail server to convince it that you're allowed to send from that address.  Here's the [instructions for GMail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en), maybe 1und1 has something similar?

Comment: were you able to solve this? I'm having the exact same problem

Comment: No i didn‘t. I now use a Gmail address with an alias, so for recievers it looks like being sent from the 1and1 address. This is not a solution for the problem, but as a hack it works just fine